# Datatables Dynamic AJAX POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

Using Datatables with AJAX / POST, I initialize like this, where experiment_list is a list, and `$("#type")` is a selector menu.

```
var my_table = $('#my_table').DataTable( {
        "ajax": {"url": "/experiment_data/", "type":"POST", "data": {"experiments": experiment_list, "type": $("#type_selector").val() } },
"dom": '<"top">rt<"bottom"fp><"clear">', 
   } );
```

The problem I am having is that `"type"` is at initialization to the selector menu value, and changing the value after that and reloading the data, does not change the value in the "ajax" method.

```
$("#type_selector").change(function () {
    console.log($("#type_selector").val()); 
    position_table.ajax.reload()
    });
```

The API Documentation only has .url() for a dynamic method, which would mean either using GET (which is not very good for object type data) or rewriting views for each selector 'type' (and changing the url on select).

Is there a way to update the Data load of the Post request Dynamically?

Comment: which v. of datatables ?

Comment: Version 1.10 of datatables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try with the sample request they provide ?

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/experiment_data/",
        "data": function ( d ) {
            d.experiments = experiment_list;
            d.type = $("#type_selector").val();
        }
    }
});
```

If it fails, can you provide the log of Firebug please ?

Comment: You're right, I was looking at a different example that was using "data" without the function (d)